# Master Detail com select2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, knockoutjs

Estou tentando fazer um master detail

Um dos inputs do mesmo é um `Select2`, Porém ele não gera o `Select2`, até por que ele é gerado apenas quando terminar de ler o script, e da segunda forma que fiz, foi fazer uma função que chama o select2, para ele sempre ser gerado, porém ele acaba zerando os outros já preenchidos

Bom meu código está assim:

```
<button type="button" id="add">Adicionar</button>
 <div class="vinculo">
</div>

    $(function () {
        $("#add").on("click", function () {
            var i = $('.vinculo input').size() + 1;
            $('<input type="text" name="vinculo[' + i + ']" id="select2vinculo' + i + '" />').appendTo(".vinculo");
        });
    });
```

e meu select2:

```
var pageSize = 10;
        $('.select2vinculo').select2(
        {
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                quietMillis: 150,
                url: '@Url.Action("Vinculos", "Select2", new { area = "" })',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (filtro, page) {
                    return {
                        pageSize: pageSize,
                        pageNum: page,
                        Filtro: filtro
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    var more = (page * pageSize) < data.total;
                    return {
                        results: data.result,
                        more: more
                    };
                }
            },
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                var vinculo = $('#select2vinculo').val();
                if (vinculo !== null && vinculo > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("BuscaVinculoId", "Select2", new { area = "" })',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { Id: vinculo },
                        success: function (data) {
                            callback(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
        })
```

Também não sei como vou capturar todos os valores, quando for editar,pois a função initSelection pega o valor do select2 e chama para setar o valor dele, que é o que faz o código, pois tenho que capturar todos para deixar selecionado, ou seja "#select2vinculo + i, onde i é gerado ao "Adicionar" o input

```
 initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                    var vinculo = $('#select2vinculo').val();
```

Alguém tem uma solução ? seja em jquery, knockout, ou qualquer outra forma de fazer um master details

Fico grato.

Comment: poderia ilustrar melhor o seu exemplo, com um print da tela por exemplo, para ter noção de como e o resultado.

Comment: Estou em duvida de algumas coisas, aqui `var vinculo = $('#vinculo').val();` você chama um elemento com "ID", porém da a entender que talvez você esteja tentando pegar ou `<div class="vinculo">` ou os "inputs" dentro do `<div class="vinculo">`, me diga o que exatamente este metodo deveria capturar? É neste ponto que você quer pegar todos inputs e envia-los pelo ajax?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no meu exemplo eu tenho uma div com class="vinculo" mas tenho os inputs que são gerados vinculos[1]

Comment: Sim isto ficou claro Rod, porém você está usando `#vinculo`, isso não captura elementos assim: `<div class="vinculo">` ele captura *um* elemento assim `<div id="vinculo">`, no seu html não tem nenhum DIV com a ID vinculo, portanto não vejo como isto poderia funcionar. Se puder ser mais claro talvez seja possível entender o seu código, por isto ainda não foi possivel reproduzir o código e entender a sua necessidade, eu aguardo.

Comment: Oi Guilherme, acho que ali no meu exemplo eu não vi, no caso que você citou, ele pega o elemento input, e seu valor para deixar já preenchido (no caso de editar o registro) aí o select2 busca o registro conforme o Val do input, acho que no exemplo não ficou claro, vou editar

Comment: Rod uma dica, quando mandar mensagem para um usuário nos comentários use o `@username`, por que senão a mensagem não chega na *inbox*, eu estou tentando ler a sua pergunta, mas ela está muito confusa, poderia revisar o texto por favor? Grato

Comment: @Rod acho que entendi, o elemento `<select>` já existe, você quer adicionar novos itens (`<option>`) para ele? É isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua questão está um pouco difícil de entender, então irei presumir primeiramente seguindo os problemas do código:

Você quer adicionar novos combos para cada vez que clicar no `#add`, se for isto, então o que o @iuristona disse está certo, o correto é usar `<select>` e não `<input>`, pois o "select2" trabalha com "selects".

- Nota: `.select2` deve ser executado depois de `.appendTo`
- Nota: Ao invés de `$('.vinculo input').size() + 1` você deve capturar os "selects", assim: `$('.vinculo select').size() + 1`
- Nota: `.size` está em desuso, use `.length`

O código deve ficar algo como isto:

```
<button type="button" id="add">Adicionar</button>
<div class="vinculo"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#add").on("click", function () {
            var i = $('.vinculo select').length + 1;//.size() está em dezuso
            var s = $('<select name="vinculo[' + i + ']"></select>');

            s.appendTo(".vinculo");

            //Select2 deve ser executado depois do appendTo, por que ele utiliza o elemento parentNode
            s.select2();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Para capturar todos os selects, bastaria algo como `$(".vinculo select[name^=vinculo]")`, você também pode usar um objeto (json) e posteriormente enviar via ajax como um "update", algo como:

```
var els = $(".vinculo select[name^=vinculo]");
var dados = {};

els.each(function() {
    dados[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});

$.ajax({
    "type": "POST", //Usando metodo POST
    "url": URL_UPDATE,//Sua url de update
    "data": dados //Envia os dados
}).then(function(response) {
    //Resposta do servidor
    console.log(response);
}).fail(function(err) {
   console.log("Erro:", err);
});
```

Para capturar os resultados com ASP.NET, você pode usar a linguagem que preferir, no caso irei mostrar um exemplo com `c#`:

```
string[] valores = Request.Form.GetValues("vinculo");
foreach (string v in valores) {
}
```

Se retornar `NULL`, use desta maneira:

```
string[] valores = Request.Form.GetValues("vinculo[]");
foreach (string v in valores) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você deseja que a cada clique no `#add` faça um append de um novo select com select2.

Antes de tudo, posso estar enganado, mas só utilizei `select2` com um elemento `select` e não com `input`. É isso mesmo, você deseja um `<input type=text />`?

Em seguida, você deveria chamar pra cada `click` o `select2();` assim:

```
$(function () {
    $("#add").on("click", function () {
        var i = $('.vinculo input').size() + 1;
        var $select = $('<select name="vinculo[' + i + ']" id="select2vinculo' + i + '" />')
        .select2({ 
           //aqui as definições do seu select2 
        });

        $select.appendTo(".vinculo");
    });
});
```

Comment: Só um comentário, você não pode usar `.select2` antes de `.appendTo` por que ele necessita de elementos como `.parentNode` para poder gerar outros elementos.